# adb says I'm running muliple emulator even if I run only one

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I have no running emulators:

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
```

but when I try to create a new one, I keep getting error:

```
$ emulator -avd phone2 -port 5552 -no-window
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
ERROR   | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
ERROR   | is an experimental feature.
ERROR   | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
```

I am running one emulator but still it says I am running multiple. How is this possible?

Comment: Have you checked the list of running processes? It may happen that there is still an emulator instance running in some error-state so that it is not visible to adb devices. Alternatively the error message ma be caused by the existence of a lock file left-over when you killed an emulator instance some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a port not in the valid range.

The range is 5554 to 5682, allowing for 64 concurrent virtual devices.

Comment: Interesting, can you given a doc link to support that?

Because after `adb kill-server` and recreating avds and emulators I am running emulator with a port outside of that range: `$ adb devices` returns: `
List of devices attached: emulator-5554   device, emulator-5552   device`

Comment: Plus you agree that the error message I was getting is misleading in such case.

Comment: Sure, it's in https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#starting